# How WSO2 TAF can be used to test WSO2 API 1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We would like to leverage the  **WSO2 Test Automation Framework(TAF) to test APIs on WSO2 API 1.7**

However since the WSO2 TAF is not a binary distribution and requires to be build from source the svn link available in the document points to the repository which has only one version of API Manager available which is **1.4**(https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/products/apimgt)

**The documentation is not quite straight forward when it comes to TAF, Would like to know if there is some other repository we should be looking at 
to test API 1.7?**

**Can someone also comment on usage of WSO2 TAF for testing APIs created using API Mgmt. I am getting a feeling that the WSO2 TAF is purely meant for product testing only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svn location for the 1.7.0 is available at [1]. The integration tests on 
[2].

The WSO2 Test Automation Framework is a maven based module which enable users to write tests using automation framework as a test engine and common utility provider which needs to write tests based on wso2 carbon products.

You can get a understanding of WSO2 Test automation framework in [3]. And you can get idea on common usage and basic steps to write a test can be get by [4], Test configuration and execution details can be found in [5].

Hope this will help you to setup a basic test suite using wso2 TAF

[1]. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/

[2].https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/modules/integration/

[3]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/platform-wide-test-automation-with-wso2-test-automation-framework/

[4]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/06/introducing-automated-tests-for-wso2-products/

[5]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/platform-test-automation-using-wso2-test-automation-framework/

Thank You,
Dharshana

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. is it recommended to use the TAF for API testing including its functionality and the configurations set on it considering it is tightly coupled with source code..  I have started believing that TAF is meant for product testing primarily..

Comment: TAF is mainly an independent testing engine where you can develop maintain and execute targeting a particular platform. It is not a direct tool but a development backbone to maintain your test suite. And execute it.